# How to ask turtles move along a specific path in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to ask turtles to move along the path that I set please see pic below:
[image]

I want people walking alone the pink path one by one (like in a queue). here's my piece of code:

```
    ;;set paths where people walk in a queue
  ask patches with [ pycor = -12 and pxcor >= 3 and pxcor <= 45 and pzcor = 0]
  [ set path 1
    set pcolor pink
  ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = -12 and pxcor >= -45 and pxcor <= -3 and pzcor = 0]
  [ set path 1
    set pcolor pink
  ]
  ask patches with [ pycor <= 12 and pycor >= -12 and pxcor = -45 and pzcor = 0]
  [ set path 1
    set pcolor pink
  ]

to go
  ask turtles [
    queue
  ]
  tick
end
to queue
  face one-of patches with [path = 1]
  ifelse [path] of patch-ahead 1 = 1
         [set heading heading - 180 fd 1] 
         [fd 1]
end
```

But this code won't give me the result as people only walking along the pink path one by one. Could anyone help me with this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  How did what you try not work like you wanted?  Why do you think it isn't working?  Posting some code might help.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for your reply. I have attached my piece of code. Hope this will help explain my question. Sorry I am quite new to Netlogo. I just want to get some ideas if Netlogo can make turtles to walk along the path one by one? Any ideas will be really appreaciated. Thanks!